# Shuffling buttons randomly android

Tags: java, android, random

Working on a word quiz [game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KCvw.png). The app fetches a definition and three words through an API and then adds them to the ui (as shown in the image). 
2 of these words are the wrong answer for the definition displayed in the textview.

So created a String array in the onPostExecute method to hold all the buttons and then tried to randomize over that array but the program generates the same results every-time.

Also, how would one prevent the randomizer from picking the same value twice? 
(i.e. 2 buttons with the same name)

```
 String[] buttons = new String[]{finalword,finaldummy1,finaldummy2};
            int first = random.nextInt(1);


        button1.setText(buttons[first]);
        button2.setText(buttons[1-first]);
        button3.setText(buttons[2-first]);
```

thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .nextInt(int n) method of the Random class returns a random decimal number between 0(inclusive) and n(exclusive). Since you have n as 1 in your example, the method will always randomly generate a number between 0 and 1, excluding 1. Once you convert a decimal to an int, all the numbers to the right of the decimal point are dropped. For example, random.nextInt(1) could return 0.654, which gets converted to the integer, zero. Therefore, the method will always return 0 because it will never return a decimal greater than 1. So the solution is simply changing `random.nextInt(1)` to `random.nextInt(3)` since you want a random integer between 0 and 2 inclusive. With the way you have it now, if the random.nextInt(3) returned 2, then button2's text will be set to buttons[1-2] aka buttons[-1] which will give an error. So you should use the absolute value function from the Math class.

```
 String[] buttons = new String[]{finalword,finaldummy1,finaldummy2};
        int first = random.nextInt(3);


        button1.setText(buttons[first]);
        button2.setText(buttons[Math.abs(first-1)]);
        button3.setText(buttons[Math.abs(first-2) + (first == 1 ? 1 : 0]);
        //the ? operator is a ternary operator
        //+ (first == 1 ? 1 : 0) translates to "if first is one, then add 1, if not, add 0
```

Comment: Thanks! That sure makes sense. However changing it to 3 gives an error. Since there are only 3 values in the array. So changing it to random.nextInt(2) works but only generates two different possible combinations where one combination has duplicate values. (i.e. sweet, candy, sweet).

Comment: ah i see why. it's because if random.nextInt(2) generated 1 for example, then the indexes will be button1.setText(buttons[1]);
                                      button2.setText(buttons[0]);
                                      button3.setText(buttons[1]); I will edit my answer to accommodate for this.

Comment: Cheers! Works perfectly now. Appreciate that! Been working on it for hours. Any ideas on how one could stop it from showing duplicates? No worries if not.

Comment: ah you're right, I forgot to take into account when random.nextInt(3) would return 1. In that case, it would the indexes would be 1, 0, and 1 so let me make the final edit to the answer.

Comment: you should take into account, however, that this will not give you every single combination of the numbers 0, 1, and 2. It will only give you the combos (0,1,2), (1,0,2), and (2,1,0), which leaves out (0,2,1), (1,2,0), and (2,0,1). Perhaps, you can try solving this on your own. Good luck on your project.

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you tried [setSeed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#setSeed(long))?
2. Why do the randomization yourself if you can just do [shuffle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Random%29).